# Get id of dynamically added checkboxes in a for loop to make them enable or disable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Below is the code that i have written but i am unable to figure out that how to get the id for the checkboxes that i have added inside a for loop on my razor page so that i can handle their enable or disable in javascript.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.CustList.Count(); i++ )
{
  <div class="custCheckboxDiv" style="float: left; margin-left: 2%; width: 25%;">
     @Html.CheckBox(Model.CustList[i].CustName, Model.CustList[i].IsCustSelected, new {@class = "custCheckbox", @disabled = "disabled" })
     @Html.Label(Model.CustList[i].CustName)
     @Html.Hidden("CustId", Model.CustList[i].CustId, new { @id = "hiddenCustId" })
  </div>  

  <div class="addToPriviledgeCust" style="float: left; width: 73%;">
     @Html.CheckBox("Add To Priviledge Customer", new { @id="@(Model.CustList[i].CustName)" })                         
     <div id="labelForaddToPriviledgeCust" style=" margin-left: 5%; width: 90%; display: block;">
        Add To Priviledge Customer
     </div>
  </div>                    
}
```

I want to enable `@id="@(Model.CustList[i].CustName)"` at the check or uncheck of `@class = "custCheckbox"` checkbox.
For this i want to assign unique ids to both the checkboxes and also to access those unique ids. Hope i am not ambiguous in what i am asking. Please help.

Comment: Don't use IDs, use DOM traversal functions by walking up and down the DOM hierarchy from `$(this)`.

Comment: using $(this) will not ambiguous as there are 2 ids that i want to access at the same time? can you give me example for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".custCheckbox").click(function() {
    var disable = !$(this).is(":checked");
    $(this).closest(".custCheckboxDiv").next().find("checkbox").prop('disabled', disable);
}
```

Comment: i can sound dumb for asking this, but what does 'closest' do? i have never used it.

Comment: It goes up the DOM hierarchy to find the closest ancestor that matches the selector. It's used all the time in jQuery DOM traversal.

Comment: ok. thanks for the info. i was not aware about it. i'll try and will let you know if i was able to get what i wanted or not. thanks again. :):)